# Vue 2 Imported Component Property or Method not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm attempting to nest some components - ultimately I would like to have a component which displays Posts, with a PostItem component used to render each post. Inside the PostItem, I want a list of related comments, with CommentItem to render each comment. I have the posts displayed using the PostItem with no errors, but as soon as I add the Comments I get errors. So to simplify, I've pulled the CommentsList component out and I'm just trying to display it on the page, manually loading in all comments - it's an exact copy of PostsList, except with comment replacing post, but it generates an error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "commment" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

found in

---> <Comment> at resources/assets/js/components/CommentItem.vue
       <CommentsList> at resources/assets/js/components/CommentsList.vue
        <Root>
```

CommentsList.vue

```
<template>
      <div class="media-list media-list-divided bg-lighter">
        <comment v-for="comment in comments"
                     :key="comment.id"
                     :comment="comment">
        </comment>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
    import comment from './CommentItem'
    export default {
        components: { comment },
        data: function() {
            return {
                comment: {
                        id: 1,
                        content: "",
                        edited: false,
                        created_at: new Date().toLocaleString(),
                        user: {
                            id: 1,
                            name: '',
                        }
                    },
                comments: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        content: "",
                        edited: false,
                        created_at: new Date().toLocaleString(),
                        user: {
                            id: 1,
                            name: '',
                        }
                    }
                ]
          };
        },
        created() {
            this.fetchCommentsList();
        },
        
        methods: {
            fetchCommentsList() {
                axios.get('/api/comments').then((res) => {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(res.data[0], null, 4));
                    this.comments = res.data;
                });
            },
 
            createComment() {
                axios.post('api/comments', {content: this.comment.content, user_id: Laravel.userId, vessel_id: Laravel.vesselId })
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.comment.content = '';
                        // this.comment.user_id = Laravel.userId;
                        // this.task.statuscolor = '#ff0000';
                        this.edit = false;
                        this.fetchCommentsList();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            },
 
            deleteComment(id) {
                axios.delete('api/comments' + id)
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.fetchCommentsList()
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

CommentItem.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a class="avatar" href="#">
            <img class="avatar avatar-lg" v-bind:src="'/images/user' + comment.user.id + '-160x160.jpg'" alt="...">
        </a>
        <div class="media-body">
            <p>
                <a href="#"><strong>{{ commment.user.name }}</strong></a>
               
            </p>
            <p>{{ comment.content }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'comment',
        props: {
            comment: {
                required: true,
                type: Object,
                default: {
                  content: "",
                  id: 1,
                  user: {
                    name: "",
                    id: 1
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
          }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I'm pretty new to Vue - I've read so many tutorials and have been digging through the documentation and can't seem to figure out why its working for me with my PostsList component thats an exact copy. It also seems odd that I need both comment and comments in the data return - something that my working Posts version requires.

I'll drop in my working Posts components:

PostsList.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-if='posts.length === 0' class="header">There are no posts yet!</div>
            <post v-for="post in posts"
                     :key="post.id"
                     :post="post">
            </post>

            <form action="#" @submit.prevent="createPost()" class="publisher bt-1 border-fade bg-white">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input v-model="post.content" type="text" name="content" class="form-control publisher-input" autofocus>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">New Post</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <span class="publisher-btn file-group">
                  <i class="fa fa-camera file-browser"></i>
                  <input type="file">
                </span>
            </form>

    </div>
</template>
<script>
    // import CommentsManager from './CommentsManager.vue';
    import post from './PostItem.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            post
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                post: {
                        id: 1,
                        content: "",
                        edited: false,
                        created_at: new Date().toLocaleString(),
                        user: {
                            id: 1,
                            name: '',
                        }
                    },
                posts: [
                    {
                        id: 1,
                        content: "",
                        edited: false,
                        created_at: new Date().toLocaleString(),
                        user: {
                            id: 1,
                            name: '',
                        }
                    }
                ]
            };
        },        
        created() {
            this.fetchPostsList();
        },
        
        methods: {
            fetchPostsList() {
                axios.get('/api/posts').then((res) => {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(res.data[0], null, 4));
                    this.posts = res.data;
                });
            },
 
            createPost() {
                axios.post('api/posts', {content: this.post.content, user_id: Laravel.userId, vessel_id: Laravel.vesselId })
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.post.content = '';
                        // this.post.user_id = Laravel.userId;
                        // this.task.statuscolor = '#ff0000';
                        this.edit = false;
                        this.fetchPostsList();
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            },
 
            deletePost(id) {
                axios.delete('api/posts' + id)
                    .then((res) => {
                        this.fetchPostsList()
                    })
                    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

PostItem.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="media bb-1 border-fade">
      <img class="avatar avatar-lg" v-bind:src="'/images/user' + post.user.id + '-160x160.jpg'" alt="...">
      <div class="media-body">
        <p>
          <strong>{{ post.user.name }}</strong>
          <time class="float-right text-lighter" datetime="2017">24 min ago</time>
        </p>
        <p><small>Designer</small></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="box-body bb-1 border-fade">
      <p class="lead">{{ post.content }}</p>

      <div class="gap-items-4 mt-10">
        <a class="text-lighter hover-light" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up mr-1"></i> 0
        </a>
        <a class="text-lighter hover-light" href="#">
          <i class="fa fa-comment mr-1"></i> 0
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
      name: 'post',
       props: {
            post: {
                required: true,
                type: Object,
                default: {
                  content: "",
                  id: 1,
                  user: {
                    name: "",
                    id: 1
                  }
                }
            }
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You have a misspelling. Change `commment` to `comment`

Comment: And from the looks of it, that should fix your issue

Comment: Also props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value, not an object literal.

Comment: You know when you stare at something so long... that you question your sanity... thanks for your commments Derek! Boy do I feel stupid.